# Create observable that combines two but is ruled by one

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

I need to combine two observables, **A** & **B**, using the following rules:

1. The type of the combined observable must be `Maybe<A>`
2. **A** may emit many times or none
3. **B** may emit 1 time or none
4. As long as **B** hasn't emitted anything, the combined observable will emit nothing.
5. When **B** emits, if **A** has emitted, the last result of **A** will be emitted by the combined observable. If **A** hasn't emitted yet, `Maybe.empty()` will be emitted.

I have tried using `combineLatest` but that doesn't work if **A** hasn't emitted yet. Also tried with `mergeWith` and doing `flatMap { if(it-was-**B**-who-emitted) Maybe.empty() else Maybe.just(emitted-item) }` but I am unable to convert from `ObservableSource` to `Maybe`

Is it possible to create such an observable in RxJava 2?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What happened?

Comment: @Michael I've updated the question with a description of what I have tried

Comment: What do you mean by "empty will be emitted"? It's in case A hasn't emitted yet

Comment: @michalbrz Updated question. It's `Maybe.empty()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done simply with default RxJava operators, but as a workaround you can make **A** emit "empty element" with your value just at the beginning. And then, using `combineLatest` you could check if emitted element is "empty element" and if it is, transform it to `Maybe.empty()` like so (example with `Observable<String>`):

```
Observable.combineLatest(
            a.startWith("EMPTY"),
            b,
            BiFunction<String, String, String> { a1, b1 -> a1 })
            .firstElement()
            .flatMap{ if (it == "EMPTY") Maybe.empty() else Maybe.just(it) }
```